# Not able to get the right pointer

Tags: c

This method returns a pointer to the first element of an int array

```
int *getNumbers(){
    int *retPtr;
    int ret[6];
    ret[0] = 1;
    ret[1] = 2;
    ret[2] = 3;
    ret[3] = 4;
    ret[4] = 5;
    ret[5] = 6;

    retPtr = ret;
    return retPtr;
}
```

At this point I can do `*(arryPtr + x)` and get the array values out fine

```
int* arryPtr = getNumbers();
int result = NumberProcess1(arryPtr);
```

Once I get into this method however I can't do that.

```
int NumberProcess1(int* numbers)
```

I keep getting eronious values and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for getNumbers?

Comment: How are you accessing `*numbers` in `NumberProcess1()`?

Comment: You are returning address of local variable

Comment: I was just doing quickwatch in VS. I would do a number of things to attempt to access it but they all throw exceptions. I was trying *(numbers) and variations mostly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ret[6];` is allocated on stack & `return retPtr` returns the address to where that variable is placed in the stack.
The thing with stack is that frames on it get `push`ed & `pop`'ed so the location your pointer points to may be over-wriiten by the next stack frame.

**Hence you should never return a pointer to a local variable.**

Allocate on `heap` instead:

```
int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: And remember to `free()` it later

Answer (score 1):

`int ret[6];` declares an array that only exists within the  `getNumbers()` function. Once that function returns, the memory is no longer valid. Trying to use it causes undefined behaviour.

One solution to this would be to make it `static int ret[6];`

Other solutions include having the caller allocate the buffer, and using dynamic allocation.

Also, the function should be `int *getNumbers(void)`  - the `void` is important as it forms a prototype.